# Issue with Md-dialog, closes when mdp-time-picker opens

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog, timepicker, angularjs-material

I need to develope a web application and to set a md-dialog with 2 md-time-picker inside. When I open the picker, the dialog closes, breaking all the process I have created with the code. I tryed this :

```
 $mdDialog.show({ 
 ...
multiple: true`,` 
... 
})`
```

'Multiple', avoid the dialog to close other dialog, but it doesn't work, bacause Angular not recognize the picker as a Dialog.

Comment: Please use the [tag:angularjs-material] tag.

Comment: I have just update the tags...